# Handle single object with two different threads with desired output

Tags: java, multithreading

If I want to update single object with two different threads how can I do ?

I tried :

```
public class BankAccount{
private static int balance;

private static void balance(int amt)throws InterruptedException{
    balance = amt;

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){

        try {
            balance(10);
            System.out.println("Initial Balance:\t"+balance);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception"+ex.getMessage());
       }

    }

});
        thread.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
}
 private static void deposit(int deposit){
        balance+=deposit;
    }

public static void main(String[] args)throws InterruptedException {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            deposit(10);
            System.out.println("Balance after deposit\t"+balance);
        }

    });
        thread.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);     
}

}
```

I know using single thread it's possible to get desired output :

Initial Balance: 10

Balance after deposit: 20

But if there is way to handle with two different threads.

Comment: Synchronized methods might be what you wish, once you have a synchronized signature for a method it can be called by various threads without any problem

Comment: I tried synchronized methods but still it wasn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to follow the below steps:

(1) Use `balance` as `AtomicInteger` to make it thread safe.

(2) Define `showBalance()`, `setBalance(int amt)` and  `deposit(int deposit)` methods first (in your code `balance(int)` is not named properly, call it as `setBalance(int amt)` to make it more meaningful)

(3) Create thread1 and call `setBalance(int amt)`

(4) Create thread2 and call `showBalance()`

(5) Create thread3 and call `deposit(int amt)`

(5) start the threads

You can refer the below code:

```
private static AtomicInteger balance = new AtomicInteger();

    private static void showBalance() {
        return balance.get();
    }

    private static void setBalance(int amt) {
        balance.set(amt);
    }

    private static void deposit(int deposit){
       balance.getAndAdd(deposit);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setBalance(10);
                System.out.println("Initial Balance\t"+balance);
            }

        });
        thread1.start();
        thread1.join();//join after completion of thread1 
                //(i.e., displays Initial Balance)

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                showBalance();
                System.out.println(" Balance\t"+balance);
            }

        });
       thread2.start();
       thread2.join();

        Thread thread3 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                deposit(10);
                System.out.println("Balance after deposit\t"+balance);
            }

        });
        thread3.start();
    }
```

Comment: balance() is some what ambiguous which has caused this problem, so I defined a new methods `showBalance()` and `setBalance(int)`

Comment: @Nizet, thanks, to make it simple, modified the code with `AtomicInteger`

Comment: Thank you so much getter and setter methods make it simple .

Comment: The thing is the method with name balance() is NOT intuitive which confused me originally, always use intuitive names like showBalance(), setBalance(), etc...

Comment: Thank you I'll be careful of it.